# How to get all jobs running on TornadoScheduler?

Tags: python, tornado, apscheduler

I am using `TornadoScheduler` of `APScheduler` python package and trying to get current running jobs.

Job configuration:

```py
...

scheduler = TornadoScheduler()

def job():
    while True:
        print('star')
        sleep(5)
        print('end')

scheduler.add_job(job)

scheduler.start()

...

tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

In other point of software, when try to get running jobs, an empty list is returned:

```py
scheduler.get_jobs() # returns empty list []
```